# How to sort by time.Time

Tags: go

I am trying to sort struct in Go by its member which is of type time.Time.
the structure is as follows.

```
type reviews_data struct {
    review_id string
    date time.Time
    score int
    firstname string
    anonymous bool
    review_text string
    title_text string
    rating float64
    upcount int
}
```

I have the below functions for sorting

```
type timeSlice []reviews_data

// Forward request for length
func (p timeSlice) Len() int {
    return len(p) 
}

// Define compare
func (p timeSlice) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return p[i].date.Before(p[j].date)
}

// Define swap over an array
func (p timeSlice) Swap(i, j int) {
    p[i], p[j] = p[j], p[i] 
}
```

A map is defined as follows

```
var reviews_data_map = make(map[string]reviews_data)
```

After the map gets filled with values,sorting of the map by values is done as below

```
//Sort the map by date
    date_sorted_reviews := make(timeSlice, 0, len(reviews_data_map))
    for _, d := range reviews_data_map {
        date_sorted_reviews = append(date_sorted_reviews, d)
    }       
    sort.Sort(date_sorted_reviews)
```

The problem is that the result is not sorted.Can anyone tell me what the problem is.

Comment: Are you *certain* they're not sorted? Your sorting code is correct.

Comment: Here is the output
Before Sorting
2014-04-16 19:57:22.096 +0000 UTC
2014-04-15 20:08:07.226 +0000 UTC
2014-04-15 20:15:16.825 +0000 UTC
2014-04-15 20:17:28.726 +0000 UTC
After Sorting
2014-04-15 20:15:16.825 +0000 UTC
2014-04-15 20:08:07.226 +0000 UTC
2014-04-15 20:17:28.726 +0000 UTC
2014-04-16 19:57:22.096 +0000 UTC

Comment: You haven't given us a short and simple working program to illustrate your problem. See my answer for an example.

Comment: This is a working program,its just that to say that the output is not sorted I added a print statement.Also this is a part of a huge program.So I have just mentioned the necessary parts.

Comment: I can't copy the code from your question and compile it. It's not a working program. See my answer for an example of a working program.

Comment: The reviews_data_map map gets populated with values from Cassandra database. Hence even if I paste the code, I think you won't be able to compile.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It looks sorted to me:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
    "time"
)

type reviews_data struct {
    review_id   string
    date        time.Time
    score       int
    firstname   string
    anonymous   bool
    review_text string
    title_text  string
    rating      float64
    upcount     int
}

type timeSlice []reviews_data

func (p timeSlice) Len() int {
    return len(p)
}

func (p timeSlice) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return p[i].date.Before(p[j].date)
}

func (p timeSlice) Swap(i, j int) {
    p[i], p[j] = p[j], p[i]
}

func main() {
    var reviews_data_map = make(map[string]reviews_data)
    reviews_data_map["1"] = reviews_data{date: time.Now().Add(12 * time.Hour)}
    reviews_data_map["2"] = reviews_data{date: time.Now()}
    reviews_data_map["3"] = reviews_data{date: time.Now().Add(24 * time.Hour)}
    //Sort the map by date
    date_sorted_reviews := make(timeSlice, 0, len(reviews_data_map))
    for _, d := range reviews_data_map {
        date_sorted_reviews = append(date_sorted_reviews, d)
    }
    fmt.Println(date_sorted_reviews)
    sort.Sort(date_sorted_reviews)
    fmt.Println(date_sorted_reviews)
}
```

Output:

```
[{ {63393534000 0 0x1ba3e0} 0  false   0 0} { {63393490800 0 0x1ba3e0} 0  false   0 0} { {63393577200 0 0x1ba3e0} 0  false   0 0}]
[{ {63393490800 0 0x1ba3e0} 0  false   0 0} { {63393534000 0 0x1ba3e0} 0  false   0 0} { {63393577200 0 0x1ba3e0} 0  false   0 0}]
```

Comment: Got the answer,There was a problem when I was printing the sorted data.Thanks @peterSO

Comment: Do I need all these secondary data structures to sort it?

Comment: Clearly, this is outdated.

Answer (score 106):

Go 1.8 and above:

```
sort.Slice(timeSlice, func(i, j int) bool {
    return timeSlice[i].date.Before(timeSlice[j].date)
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any cons of using sort.Slice compared to the accepted answer?

Comment: The most significant disadvantage of the given function is that it uses reflection, which indeed is slower than doing the thing "by hand". For small slices, there is no difference, but if you expect to have bigger slices it is better to use another method.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done below go 1.8 without the extra type and map in the accepted answer.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "sort"
)

type reviews_data struct {
    review_id   string
    date        time.Time
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Sort Example")
    var listOfReviews = make([]reviews_data, 0)
    listOfReviews = append(listOfReviews, reviews_data{review_id: "1",date:time.Now()})
    listOfReviews = append(listOfReviews, reviews_data{review_id: "2",date: time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, 7*1)})
    listOfReviews = append(listOfReviews, reviews_data{review_id: "1",date: time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, 7*-1)})

    sort.Slice(listOfReviews, func(i, j int) bool { return listOfReviews[i].date.Before(listOfReviews[j].date) })
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Go 1.21 update**

You can now use slices.SortFunc for any type and the builtin Time.Compare function:

```
slices.SortFunc(yourSlice, func(a, b T) int { return a.Date.Compare(B.Date) })
```

Ref:

- https://pkg.go.dev/slices#SortFunc
- https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time.Compare

Comment: This is what I was looking for! slices.SortFunc now needs an int rather than a bool

Answer (score 0):

> sorting dates

```
type Location struct {
  Lat     float64   `json:"lat"`
  Lng     float64   `json:"lng"`
  Thetime time.Time `json:"thetime"`
}
func sorttime(dat []Location) {
  for i := 0; i < len(dat); i++ {
    for j := i + 1; j < len(dat); j++ {
      if dat[i].Thetime.Unix() < dat[j].Thetime.Unix() {
        dat[i], dat[j] = dat[j], dat[i]
      }
    }
  }
}
```