# Sort slice of structs by Time date field in go 1.2 without creating a secondary structure

Tags: sorting, go, time

This answer here [Sorting by time.Time in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23121026/sorting-by-time-time-in-golang)

tries to sort with a secondary array with a map

```
type timeSlice []reviews_data
```

Can golang slices of objects with dates be sorted by without creating this secondary data structure?

Given a struct like

```
type SortDateExample struct {
    sortByThis time.Time
    id string
}
```

And a slice initialized something like

```
var datearray = var alerts = make([]SortDateExample, 0)
dateSlice = append(dateSlice,newSortDateExmple)
dateSlice = append(dateSlice,newSortDateExmple2)
dateSlice = append(dateSlice,newSortDateExmple3)
```

How can I sort array by the time field sortByThis?

Answer (score 8):

**With Go 1.8 and above**

```
sort.Slice(dateSlice, func(i, j int) bool { 
    return dateSlice[i].sortByThis.Before(dateSlice[j].sortByThis) 
})
```

https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Slice

**With Go below 1.8**

In that case, you don't need a `map`, but you do need to define a type for your array:

```
type SortedDateExampleArray []SortDateExample
```

Then you need that array type to implement the methods in `sort.Interface`.

```
func (a SortedDateExampleArray) Len() int {
    return len(a)
}

func (a SortedDateExampleArray) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return a[i].sortByThis.Before(a[j].sortByThis)
}

func (a SortedDateExampleArray) Swap(i, j int) {
    a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
}
```

And then you can use `sort.Sort` to sort your custom array.

https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Sort

Comment: Does this need go 1.8?

Comment: Yes: https://golang.org/doc/go1.8#sort_slice

Comment: @camccar, I see you edited your question to note it is Go 1.2, so I included the "With Go below 1.8" section in my answer.

Comment: Ugh, do I really have to define a type? I have an array of a struct i'm using already

Comment: Only if you want to reuse the Go's libraries sort functions, the other option is to implement a sorting function over your array yourself.